# Setting Margin to LinearLayout without setting width and height

Tags: android, android-layout

i got a small problem and i stuck on this for very long.

I got an Android Application, there is a LinearLayout and i fill this linearlayout with other elements dynamically in my code, depending on user inputs. The element i add, gets a drawable resource as background, in which width and height is defined.

My Problem:
When i want to set margin to these elements via `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` i have to pass width and height values in the contructor and this will overwrite the width and height values from my drawable.

 
I tried something like this:

```
    this.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.board_element) ;
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
    params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 10) ;
    this.setLayoutParams(mparams) ;
```

also tried this:

```
this.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.board_element) ;
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) this.getLayoutParams();
params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 10) ;
    this.setLayoutParams(params) ;
```

My drawble resource:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">
   <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/dark_brown" />
   <solid 
       android:color="@color/dark_brown"/>
   <corners
       android:radius="10dp" />
   <size 
       android:width="200dp"
       android:height="50dp" />
   <padding 
       android:left="5dp"
       android:top="9dp"
       android:right="10dp"
       android:bottom="5dp"/>

</shape>
```

But this doesn´t work, width and height were both 0. Are there any suggestions ? 
My minimum API Level is 9 max 19.

Comment: have you tried `getMeasuredWidth()` and `getMeasuredHeight()`?

Comment: @ataulm didnt work either.

Comment: maybe post your custom view class, and the XML layout too.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
```

Comment: this doesnt work, it overwrites my widht and height values from the xml.

Comment: what exactly you want?

Answer (score 0):

```
LayoutParams p = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            p.setMargins(7, 8, 8, 8);
            LinearLayout llp = new LinearLayout(this);
            llp.setLayoutParams(p);
            llp.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.survey_answer_box);
```

Comment: try to `Edit` ur answer instead of posting another answer in same `question`